# Giving a state value from another component class through using a prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am completely new in React Native and I am trying to improve my self with some making sample apps. For this scenario, I only want that when the `Button` is pressed, the state and the value of the toggle change, such as `CLOSED` and `OPEN`. And `Make Open` is not changed. Now, I have three class components. I am not going to give App's class. I've alread completed it. In this class, I have added a prop:

```
class A extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
      this.state = {change: true};
    }
    render(){ 
     
     return(
      <View>
          <View ...
            <Text>CLOSED</Text>
          </View>
      </View>  
           
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my second class B:

```
class B extends Component
{
  state = {isOpen : false};
  render()
  {
    onPress = () => {
       ...
    })
  }
    return(
       <View> 
         <View ...
            <A/>
            <Button 
               title="Make Open"
               onPress={this.onPress}
            />
          </View>
      </View>       
    );
  }
}
```

I am struggling with the prop. My question is that I want to pass the `isOpen` value from the `class B`'s state to `class A` by use of this prop. I think that I could not create state in `class B`. What is the easiest way to solve this problem ? If I gave not enough information, sorry for that.

Comment: you can send isOpen value to A component like this ```<A isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />``` and then in A component you can access the value with ```this.props.isOpen```, if I understood well

Comment: I realized that, I have also some problems with changing the text `CLOSED` to `OPEN`. Am I going to initialize this values in the  A component with using another method?

Comment: to put a text according to ```isOpen``` value, you can do ```<Text>{this.props.isOpen ? "OPENED" : "CLOSED"}</Text>```

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you call component A from component B, you have to pass your state like so:

```
<A isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
```

Then in component A, you can simply access it with *props.isOpen*.